# XPath works in Chrome Inspect but not on PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to use OR operator in XPath, and it works on Chrome Inspect. But it makes it not working on PHP. The initial XPath without OR operator was working just fine in PHP.

This is the initial XPath:

```
//h4[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::*[not(@class)][not(@style)]
```

This is the modified XPath

```
//h4[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::*[not(@class)|@class="MsoNormal"][not(@style)]
```

Sorry, I can't mention the link because of job disclosure.

After the modified XPath, I got this error from the PHP script:

```
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid type in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP projects\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\custom\class_ff_parser.php on line 660

Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP projects\<project_name>\<project_name>\lib\custom\class_ff_parser.php on line 660
```

Comment: Please provide a small example of the XML and your code that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to leave a comment but my reputation is too low.

Rather than using "|" as your OR operator, perhaps use the word "or". It may be that your php script may not be able to parse the "|" character.

So:

```
//h4[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::*[not(@class) or @class="MsoNormal"][not(@style)]
```

It would be really helpful if we could see the code on the line that's causing your issue.